# How to make `emacs` shell command switch to existing emacs process, if it exists?

Tags: command-line-arguments

Is there a way to get the `emacs` shell command (the UNIX utility) to start an emacs process, if none exists, but if one does, switch to it?

More specifically, is there a way to get the command `emacs file1 file2` visit `file1` and `file2` in the *existing* emacs process, if one already exists?

BTW, I'm not sure how to tag this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you should run `(server-start)` within emacs. This can be put in your init file.

The command you are looking for is `emacsclient --no-wait --alternate-editor=emacs`. You can put this behind an alias if you want. This will open the files on the existing server and frame if there is one, and will otherwise run emacs as usual. The `--no-wait` is optional and prevents the command from blocking the terminal.

Comment: The equivalent short options are `emacsclient -n -a emacs`. You can also use an empty string for the fallback editor arg to "start Emacs in daemon mode and try connecting again". `emacsclient -n -a ''`